# How do I transform all elements of a varadic std::tuple using numerical indices?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

Currently, I have an implementation like this in order to transform all values of a tuple using a function `bar()` that takes in each element of the tuple.

```
template<typename ... Args>
void foo(const std::tuple<Args...>& a)
{
    std::tuple<Args...> transformedTuple = std::make_tuple(bar(std::get<Args>(a))...);
}
```

The problem with this is that this will no longer work if `Args` contains duplicate types. Hence, I would like to change the `std::get<>` call to use numerical indices into the tuple instead of using types. Given that my development environment is stuck on C++14, is there any way of getting this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a helper function that takes a [`std::integer_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to do this.  Add a helper function that takes an `integer_sequence` like

```
template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... I>
auto foo_helper(const Tuple& a, std::integer_sequence<std::size_t, I...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(bar(std::get<I>(a))...);
}
```

And then changing `foo` to call the helper like

```
template<typename ... Args>
auto foo(const std::tuple<Args...>& a)
{
    return foo_helper(a, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{});
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9XjjWywZHyRZ55zX)

Comment: Thanks! This works out really well and solves the problem rather elegantly!

Answer (score 4):

In C++17, you might do

```
template<typename ... Args>
void foo(const std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
    auto transformedTuple =
        std::apply([](const auto&... args){ return std::make_tuple(bar(args)...); }, t);
}
```