# Using a pack expansion with an index - is it UB?

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

The code below "seems" to work - however, I'm a little concerned that I'm in the realms of unspecified behaviour at the marked point.  If I am, can someone please throw me a bone so that I can ensure that I'm not going to have it suddenly break when I change compiler?

The intent (in case it isn't clear) is that I want to generate a std::function that is able to wrap another - but process the arguments in a slightly different way.

```
/// Some collection of arguments generated at runtime.
class ArgCollection 
{
   int argCount;
   std::variant *arguments;
}

/// generate the wrapping fn
template<class ...Args>
std::function<void(ArgCollection)> GetConvert(std::function<void(Args...)> thing)
{
    constexpr std::size_t argCount = sizeof...(Args);
    return [argCount, method](const ArgCollection& args) -> void {
        if (args.numArguments != argCount)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid number of arguments");

        int count = 0;  <------------ I fear about the usage of this variable.
        auto convertedArgs = std::make_tuple(ConvertArg<Args>(args, count++)...);
        std::apply(method, convertedArgs);
    };
}

/// helper const & reference stripping
template<typename T>
using base_type = typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::type;

/// Get the idx'th argument, and convert it to what we can hand to the function
template<class T>
static base_type<T> ConvertArg(const ArgCollection &args, int idx)
{
    return base_type<T>(args[idx]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, the increments can happen in any order. Was UB before C++17, now the increments are just indeterminately sequenced relative to each other. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thought that would be the case - any thoughts about how to get the index from the unpacking?

Comment: Try to rewrite it using `std::tuple{...}`, with curly braces. Initializers in curly braces are executed sequentally.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and that's the line that was missing from the eval order page ;)  perfect, thanks a ton!  (If you want to make a form of answer from that I'm happy to send you points)

Comment: You could add a `std::integer_sequence` and then use `std::make_index_sequence` to get the correct sequence. This lets you have a pack of types, and a pack indices that matches the types.  You can see an example of that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68445611/4342498

Comment: Couldn't you use a stateful lambda with "count" in the capture and declared mutable?

Comment: @UKMonkey, It's #10: *In list-initialization, every value computation and side effect of a given initializer clause is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with any initializer clause that follows it in the brace-enclosed comma-separated list of initalizers.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
auto convertedArgs = std::make_tuple(ConvertArg<Args>(args, count++)...);
```

the increments are indeterminately sequenced relative to each other.  Compilers are free to do them in any order, and change the order because a butterfly flaps its wings.  (Prior to [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) the guarantees where worse than this)

In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) there is an easy work around:

```
constexpr std::size_t argCount = sizeof...(Args);
return [&]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
  return [argCount, method](const ArgCollection& args) -> void {
    if (args.numArguments != argCount)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid number of arguments");

    auto convertedArgs = std::make_tuple(ConvertArg<Args>(args, Is)...);
    std::apply(method, convertedArgs);
  };
}( std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Args)>{} );
```

where we make an index sequence object and unpack it in a lambda within the function.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) you basically need helper functions that build and unpack the indexes.

```
template<auto x>
using constant_t = std::integral_constant<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, x>;
template<auto x>
constexpr constant_t<x> constant_v={};

template<std::size_t...Is, class F>
decltype(auto) index_over( std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f ) {
  return f( constant_v<Is>... );
}
template<std::size_t N, class F>
decltype(auto) index_upto(F&& f) {
  return index_over( std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, std::forward<F>(f) );
}
```

then your code becomes:

```
constexpr std::size_t argCount = sizeof...(Args);
return index_upto<argCount>([&](auto...Is){
  return [argCount, method, Is...](const ArgCollection& args) -> void {
    if (args.numArguments != argCount)
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid number of arguments");

    auto convertedArgs = std::make_tuple(ConvertArg<Args>(args, Is)...);
    std::apply(method, convertedArgs);
  };
});
```

or somesuch.

You can also write a more conventional helper function that you pass an index sequence to.

Finally, you can rely on the fact that `{}` based initialization is ordered.

```
template<class ...Args>
std::function<void(ArgCollection)> GetConvert(std::function<void(Args...)> thing)
{
    constexpr std::size_t argCount = sizeof...(Args);
    return [argCount, method](const ArgCollection& args) -> void {
        if (args.numArguments != argCount)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid number of arguments");

        int count = 0;  <------------ I fear about the usage of this variable.
        auto convertedArgs = std::tuple{ConvertArg<Args>(args, count++)...};
        std::apply(method, convertedArgs);
    };
}
```

which could be easier.